# How to set GROOVY_HOME environment variable on Ubuntu

Tags: command-line, environment-variables

I am a novice, who is new to Linux and I am trying to set GROOVY_HOME environment variable.
Note sure if this is the right step:

```
GROOVY_HOME='/usr/share/groovy'
```

Also trying to add `$GROOVY_HOME/bin` to my `$PATH` environment variable, but I am not too sure on how to do this. Any ideas/steps on what to do would be appreciated.

Comment: How you installed groovy? via .deb file or how?

Comment: I have the groovy binary distribution on a local file system, which i copied across to the local file system on the target server in Ubuntu -- /usr/share/groovy...

Answer (score 3):

Create the file `/etc/profile.d/groovy.sh` by opening a terminal window and running this command:

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/profile.d/groovy.sh
```

Give the file this contents:

```
export GROOVY_HOME=/usr/share/groovy
PATH="$PATH:$GROOVY_HOME/bin"
```

Then save, log out and log in again.

Comment: Thanks. Can you please tell me the steps to create the file -- /etc/profile.d/groovy.sh

Comment: @DonOntime: I just did, I think. Run the command I suggested.

Comment: I have just tried the above step, but do encounter this: Sudo:unable to change to root gid: operation not permitted and also sudo: unable to initialise policy plug-in

Comment: @DonOntime: I assumed you were logged in as a user with admin privileges. If you are logged in as root you can skip the `sudo -H` part. Otherwise you need to switch to an admin user account.

Comment: @kaviranga: ???

Comment: @kaviranga: 1. I didn't suggest `~/.bashrc`, so I'm not sure how your comment is relevant. 2. `source ~/.bashrc` may make a difference in the current terminal window, but it does not change anything permanently.